# How to Overload an Operator in JavaScript/UnityScript?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading, unityscript

I asked this question on Unity Answers, but yet again there was no response. Now I'm hoping someone on SO will happen to know the answer since it *is* a programming question.

There are quite a few of these questions, but I couldn't find any more recent than about 2009 and a lot has changed since then. *So...*

In Unity 5, is it possible to overload an operator (specifically the + operator) when using JavaScript/UnityScript?

**-- Additional Information --**

I have a class like so:

```
class Vector3Int
{
    var x:int;
    var y:int;
    var z:int;
    function Vector3Int(nX:int,nY:int,nZ:int)
    {
        x=nX;
        y=nY;
        z=nZ;
    }
}
```

I wish to be able to do the following...

```
var position1:Vector3Int=new Vector3Int(5,39,-2);
var position2:Vector3Int=new Vector3Int(83,3,148);

print(position1+position2);
```

...and have the output be `88,42,146`.

Comment: can you give me an example of what are you trying to do?

Comment: I've created a Vector3Int class that looks like this:


 class Vector3Int
 {
  var x:int;
  var y:int;
  var z:int;
  function Vector3Int()
  {
   x=0;
   y=0;
   z=0;
  }

Comment: Oops, hangon I'll try to get it readable...

Comment: @Sekretoz I've got a Vector3Int class (that just has x, y and z vars inside it) and I want to be able to easily add two of them together, or add a Vector3Int to a built-in Vector3. That sort of thing. Dead-easy in C++.

Comment: example you want to add x and y?

Comment: @Sekretoz What you just said makes no sense. I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: and i also cannot understand what youre trying to do.

Comment: @Sekretoz I have created a new class. It has the members X, Y and Z. I want to be able to create a variable which is an instance of that class, then add it (using the + operator) to another instance of the class and have the member variables be added together (so X + X, Y + Y, Z + Z). I've updated the OP in case you still can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it wont be possible to add two class directly.try this code to add value of two class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript{
     public int x;
     public int y;
     public int z;


    public NewBehaviourScript(int nx,int ny,int nz){
        x = nx;
        y = ny;
        z = nz;
    }

}
```

class to get sum of two classes

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sum {

 public NewBehaviourScript sumOfTwoClass(NewBehaviourScript a, NewBehaviourScript b)
    {

        return new NewBehaviourScript (a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
    }
}
```

main class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sample : MonoBehaviour {

    NewBehaviourScript zzz;
    NewBehaviourScript xxx;
    public NewBehaviourScript sum;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        zzz = new NewBehaviourScript (1, 2, 3);
        xxx = new NewBehaviourScript (3, 2, 1);
        sum = new sum ().sumOfTwoClass (zzz, xxx);
    }
}
```

Comment: "sumOfTwoClass" This is what I was trying to avoid. I already use that hacky solution but I wanted a neater and better way. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
public class Vector3Int {
public  int x;
public int y;
public int z;

public Vector3Int(int nX, int nY, int nZ)
{
    x=nX;
    y=nY;
    z=nZ;
}

public static Vector3Int operator +(Vector3Int c1, Vector3Int c2)
{
    return new Vector3Int(c1.x + c2.x, c1.y + c2.y, c1.z+c2.z);
}
```

}

To test:

```
  Vector3Int a = new Vector3Int(1, 2, 3);
    Vector3Int b = new Vector3Int(4, 5, 6);
    a = a + b;
    Debug.Log(a.x +" "+a.y+" "+a.z);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is that even JavaScript?

Comment: It's not Javascript, it's C#..As far as I know you can write classes in C# and than use them in Javascript :)

Comment: What? How? I don't know how to write C#, let alone how to use its classes in JS! :S